# Japanese characters are blank in the PDF generated by java code using iText library when deployed on docker only

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, itext

I am trying to generate PDF file with Japanese+English characters. The code runs fine on local but when I deploy the application (java spring boot) on docker then the Japanese characters are blank.
Here is my code:

```
Service Class
@Service
public class ServiceClassImpl implements ServiceClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceClassImpl.class);
    private BaseFont baseFont;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadBaseFont() throws DocumentException, IOException {
        ClassPathResource cp = new ClassPathResource("notosans.otf");
        if (cp.exists()) {
            File file = cp.getFile();
            baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(file.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ByteArrayInputStream get() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
            document.open();

            PdfPTable table = createReportTable();
            document.add(table);

            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception inside get() in ServiceClassImpl {} ", e);
        }

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }
}

Controller
@GetMapping(value = "/pdf", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getPdf() {
    ByteArrayInputStream testFile = serviceClass.get();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=testFile.pdf");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(testFile));
}

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:11
ADD  ./target/app-1.0.0.jar /opt/app-1.0.0.jar

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/app-1.0.0.jar"]
```

Hope you can help me out here as I have been stuck on this for a while now and I can't get any of the solutions to work. If there is any information I have missed to mention, or I have mentioned a wrong info, please do tell me so that I can update.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have added font file into docker using docker file and given the path to base font and it worked. For some reasons it wasn't picking up the font file from resource folder.

```
@Value("${filepath.font.arialuni:/opt/fonts/arialuni.TTF}") 
private String arialuniFontFilePath;
@PostConstruct
public void loadBaseFont() throws DocumentException, IOException {
    baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(arialuniFontFilePath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
}

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:11
ADD  ./target/app-1.0.0.jar /opt/app-1.0.0.jar
ADD  ./src/main/resources/arialuni.ttf /opt/fonts/arialuni.ttf

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/app-1.0.0.jar"]
```